# Fullcalendar: Json not reflecting in the fullcalendar

Tags: php, json, fullcalendar

I am trying to fetch events from an external php file onto the full calendar view. I had asked a similar question sometime back but I am still struggling with this thing.

**CODE (JS):**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#ccategory').change(function(){
            var id = $(this).val();
            var user = $('#current_user').val();
            var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
events: {
    url: '<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/get_calcat_calendar.php',
    data: function() { // a function that returns an object
        return {
            dynamic_value1: id,
            dynamic_value2: user
        };
    }              
                error: function() {
                  alert('There was an error while fetching events.');
                }                  
              }
            }); 
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Also I am going to add the file which is generating the json file below:

**PHP CODE:**

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $title = get_the_title($row['ID']);
    $url = get_permalink($row['ID']);
    $e = array();
    $e['title'] = $title;
    $e['url'] = $url;
    $e['start'] = $row['start_date'];
    $e['end'] = $row['end_date'];       
    $e['color'] = '#33cc33';

    array_push($events, $e);
}

echo json_encode($events);
exit();
```

This is the code which I am using the fetch the json from the database. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank You

**REQUIREMENT UPDATE:**

```
[{"title":"Timeout72","url":"http:\/\/www.goawebsites.com\/goacalendar\/event\/timeout72\/","start":"2017-11-29","end":"2017-12-31","color":"#33cc33"}]
```

`<div id='calendar'></div>`

**OTHER CALENDAR SCRIPT:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var user_id = $('#current_user').val(); 
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
displayEventTime: false,

    events: [
        <?php foreach($result as $r) { ?>
            {
            <?php $title = get_the_title($r['event_id']); ?>
            <?php $url = get_permalink($r['event_id']); ?>
            title: '<?php echo html_entity_decode($title); ?>',
            start: '<?php echo $r['start_date'] ?>',
            end: '<?php echo $r['end_date']." 23:59:59" ?>',
            url: '<?php echo $url; ?>',
            color: '#33cc33'
            },
        <?php } ?>  
    ]   

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: we'll need a bit more info than "still struggling". What goes wrong? Ajax error, JS error, PHP error, something else?? BTW why are you re-creating the entire calendar every time your "change" event runs? Surely you just need to make it refetch the events but sending a different category ID?

Comment: Nothing happens. No error that is why I am stuck. What else would you need?

Comment: have you checked in your browser's network tab to see if the request to get_calcat_calendar.php actually happens? If it does, what does it return (status code, and response body)? If it doesn't run, have you checked your "change" event is actually running, and without generating script errors? In other words what I need is some basic debugging info

Comment: I have added alerts when an option has been selected, which are working. But nothing shows on the network tab

Comment: Is a calendar even being created? Even if the event fetching failed you should still see a blank calendar appear, unless there's a script error in the console, or your HTML element doesn't exist. Can you show the HTML associated with this, please?

Comment: The calendar is displaying properly with events. However when I select an option from the dropdown. It doesn't map to the calendar. I will edit my question to give you the json and the calendar div

Comment: So you are initialising the calendar somewhere else _as well_ before an option is selected? You have another `$('#calendar').fullCalendar({` declaration somewhere else in your code?

Comment: Updated the question and yes it is initialized elsewhere before.

Comment: Ok well there's no need to do that, all that's actually changing when you select a category is one single parameter being sent to the server, no need to re-create the whole calendar. Use the pattern shown here in the "Dynamic data parameter" section to define your category ID variable: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/ , that way you can supply `$('#ccategory').val()` to it. Now, in the "change" event, all you need to do is run "refetchEvents" and it'll pick up the new category value automatically. Try that, if you get stuck again post updated code and I'll help.

Comment: 2 actually, because it is getting the calendar based on the category and the user.

Comment: Ok fine but the same principle will apply I think

Comment: Updating question for reference.

Comment: Just seen your update. I think you mis-understood what I was trying to say. I've posted an answer which hopefully is clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be more like what you need:

1) When you first set up your calendar, define your extra "user" and "category" data parameters dynamically (using a callback function).

2) Inside your category "change" event, all you need to do now is simply tell the calendar to refetch the events. There is no need to completely re-initialise the calendar, as you have been doing.

I can't see all of the code, including where you first initialise the calendar, so this may not be 100% accurate, but this is the general idea:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: {
      url: '<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/get_calcat_calendar.php',
      data: function() { //using a callback function here allows fullCalendar to fetch the latest values of these parameters every time it makes a new request to the server, rather than them being supplied statically at initialisation
        return {
            id: $('#ccategory').val(),
            user: $('#current_user').val()
        };
      },
      error: function() {
        alert('There was an error while fetching events.');
      }
    }
  });

  $('#ccategory').change(function() {
     //just tell the calendar re-fetch the events. It will automatically get the latest category ID value and send it to the server as a parameter
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
  });
});
```

This is based on the pattern shown in the "Dynamic data parameter" section in the documentation at  https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/

Comment: Hi ADyson, thanks for the reply. Will this not affect my previous calendar script? I am adding it in the question for reference.

Comment: The example here is intended to replace both the code in your question, and your main calendar script, yes.

Comment: I see you've now added your main calendar script. Yes, definitely, this code should replace all of it. You only need to declare the calendar once. Your PHP script should be able to cope with there being no "user" or "category" option selected initially. It should also accept the start and end parameters which fullcalendar supplies to it automatically (see the docs). What you were doing before was hard-coding your events into the javascript rendered to the page, instead of fetching them via ajax when the view changes (or refetchEvents is called), which is a much more flexible approach.

Comment: Hi ADyson, Sorry for the delay. Now my calendar isn't loading at all, and console is displaying `Uncaught Syntax Error Unexpected Identifier` on `error: function() {
        alert('There was an error while fetching events.');
      }` section of the code.

Comment: Sorry it was just a simple JS syntax error - I missed the comma out before that bit. See the edited answer. `events` is an object with a list of properties (url, data and error) and each property needs a comma between it and the next one. Once you get to know JS a bit more that sort of thing will be simple to fix :-)

Comment: Hi ADyson. It&#39;s still not working. Is there any other way I can do this? I am not getting any error in console either.

Comment: What about in the network tab? Server-side errors? I've used this design pattern many times before and it works with no issue. You clearly have missed something in your implementation but it's hard to be sure without sufficient debugging detail.

Comment: Is there anyway to see what is the response I get in an alert or something like that?

Comment: Not easily in this implementation, but you don't need to. Just look in your browser's Network tab, in the tools. Find the ajax request which is being made to get_calcat_calendar.php. Check it returns a "200 OK" response in the first instance. Click on it. Check the bottom of the Headers tab and see if your parameter values were sent to the server correctly. Then click on the "Response" tab. In there you can see exactly what was returned by the server. (These instructions are for Chrome, but should be similar in other browsers). Much better than cramming it into an alert.

Comment: It's returning blank JSON. I will have a look at it and see what is the issue and get back to you if it works. Thanks

Comment: Does it work once you select a category? Perhaps the server is not dealing well with the case where the default option is selected? Do you have an "all" option in your dropdown? What does it send to the server? Does the server understand this and adapt the query accordingly?

Comment: Yeah there is some issue with the data being sent but I also should handle it on server side for all the calendar listings

Comment: "some issue". What issue, exactly?

Comment: Hello ADyson, extremely sorry for the late reply. I got it working. 1 issue was that id was taking the user's value and user was taking the category's value. And secondly, I had didn't handle the category being blank from the file that was fetching the date. I have edited your question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem, that was another silly typo on my part, sorry it caused you extra trouble. Thanks for editing.

Comment: Don't worry about it, just grateful for your help